# Block users who use fake location iphone apps

Tags: ios, gps

I want to write an app that is depend on iphone GPS location. but i saw there is some apps that can send fake data location to other apps like http://iphonehelp.in/2009/12/17/fakelocation-lets-you-to-fake-your-gps-location/ or  FakeLocation in Cydia or with connect phone to the xcode simulator.

Is there any solution to detect that a user used a fake location or not? Or is there a way to know that phone which user useing, is jailbroken or not?

Answer (score 1):

One simple (but not 100% foolproof) way to check if a device is jailbroken is to check for typical jailbreak artifacts on startup, for example in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"] ||
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/private/var/lib/apt"]) {
        // Device is jailbroken
        abort();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you flatby, it seems good. but about first question, don't you have any idea about, how to detect GPS fake location?